# "Separated" Chrome.storage for every tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have this situation where via content script I get data from DOM of web page. I need to pass this data to *popup page* of browser action extension.

It works well but chrome.storage variables are shared so I have same data everywhere.

***For example:*** Let's have a script which gets URL after '/'. So from google.com/one on first tab and google.com/two on second, my extension gets only 'two'. My point is I need to separate these storage spaces for every tab or find another way to solve this.

Comment: Maybe use a unique identifier for each tab?
This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6585331/2033574) suggests using tabid as a key.

Comment: What code does your extension use to access tab data?

Comment: If the data isn't big (say, less than 100kB stringified) passing it with `sendMessage` might be a better solution (provided you don't need to keep the data between browsing sessions).

Comment: yea, it's just like 100 characters long string, probably I'm going to use message passing, thank you  .. btw now it's only content script -> background page -> popup or there is simpler way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I have broken up your post.  Please do not use <br> tags, use a blank line instead.  It would help others to help you faster if you posted what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JakubFedor, to answer that a more complete info is required (the relevant code, etc).

Comment: is there any solution for this?